# How to do Conditional Column Joins in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a tables below

Main Table: tblMain

```
Phase   Country   City    
AAA     India     Bangalore
AAA     USA       Chicago
ZZZ     USA
ZZZ     UK
```

SubTable: tblSub

```
Phase   Country City    Value
AAA     USA     Chicago   3
AAA     USA     NY        6
AAA     UK      London    5
AAA     India   Bangalore 6
AAA     India   Delhi     9
ZZZ     USA     Chicago   7
ZZZ     UK      London    8
```

Expected Result

```
 Phase   Country   City        Value
  AAA     India     Bangalore   6
  AAA     USA       Chicago     3
  ZZZ     USA                   7 
  ZZZ     UK                    8
```

I want to join this with my Main table which has Phase, Country and City, however the condition is 
For Phase "ZZZ" i want to join only by Country where as for Phase "AAA" i want to join ty Country & City. Is is possible to do in SQL Query without a Stored procedure or temp tables
I am looking to achieve this in plain query. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM This_Table TT 
LEFT JOIN Main_Table MT  ON TT.Countrry = MT.Country  
                        AND TT.Phase = 'ZZZ'
LEFT JOIN Main_Table MT2 ON TT.Countrry = MT2.Country 
                        AND TT.City = MT2.City 
                        AND TT.Phase = 'AAA'
```

Comment: Thanks Ali! With the query how do i select Value?

Comment: Not a problem, Just add the column names in select statement instead of the `*` make sure you use two part name i.e `TableName.ColumnName` in your case you will use the `TableAlias.ColumnName`.

Comment: Something like this???   SELECT TT.Phase, TT.Country, TT.City, MT.Value, MT2.Value FROM This_Table TT 
LEFT JOIN Main_Table MT  ON TT.Countrry = MT.Country  
                        AND TT.Phase = 'ZZZ'
LEFT JOIN Main_Table MT2 ON TT.Countrry = MT2.Country 
                        AND TT.City = MT2.City 
                        AND TT.Phase = 'AAA'

Comment: You have literally copy pasted my query, you need to use the actual table names and column names :S .

Comment: i know but instead of * if i give value columns i get two different columns now..

Comment: Edited my question to give better understanding. Please lookinto that

Comment: Oh right I get you know Use `COALESCE( MT.Value, MT2.Value)` and same for any other double columns.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
WHERE 
    (a.phase = 'ZZZ' AND a.country = b.country)
        OR
    (a.phase = 'AAA' AND a.country = b.country AND a.city = b.city)
```

Comment: Can you provide me the full query, assume my main table name is mainTable and has Phase, Country, City columns

Comment: You mostly have it in your comment to M.Ali's post. This community does expect you to do some work yourself. Two viable solutions have been presented to overcome the issue you were facing. That should be enough and you should be able to take it from here.